# ActiveRecord table does not exist error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jdbc

Why am I getting a table not found error?

```
?> >> User.connection.execute("select * from users where rownum = 1")
=> //successful result

?> >> User.first
DEPRECATION WARNING: the object returned from `select_all` must respond to `column_types`. (called from first at C:0)
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Table users does not exist

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection 'db1'
  alias_attribute(:site_type_id, :'SITE_TYPE#ID')
end
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing `User.where("rownum = 1").first` ?

Comment: @Vimsha Doesn't matter 

`?> >> User.where('rownum = 1')
DEPRECATION WARNING: the object returned from `select_all` must respond to `column_types`. (called from IRB at C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/irb/inspector.rb:86)
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Table users does not exist`

Comment: what does your migration for the users table look like?

Comment: @user3334690 added info to question

Comment: What is the primary key on the users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the issue...  ActiveRecord doesn't like the ojdbc driver jar.  As soon as I switched from OJDBC to the OracleEnhanced adapter it worked!